# Few (specific everytime) contacts duplicated during insert in android

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

I am trying to insert a list of contacts in android using Contact API. But I am facing a strange problem with that. Some of the contact is getting duplicated if they exist in the phone book. But this happens to only a few of the contacts not to all the contacts which confused me more.

Here is my code.

```
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> restoredContactList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
restoredContactList.clear();
restoredContactList
.add(ContentProviderOperation
    .newInsert(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
        mAccountType)
    .withValue(
        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
        mAccountName).build());

for (int j = 0; j < namesArray.length(); j++) {
    final JSONObject nameObj = namesArray
    .getJSONObject(j);

    restoredContactList
    .add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            0)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME,
            nameObj.getString("first_name")
            + " "
            + nameObj
            .getString("last_name"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
            nameObj.getString("first_name"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME,
            nameObj.getString("last_name"))
        .build());
}

// Phone
final JSONArray phonesArray = obj
.getJSONArray("phones");
for (int j = 0; j < phonesArray.length(); j++) {

    final JSONObject phoneObj = phonesArray
    .getJSONObject(j);

    restoredContactList
    .add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            0)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            phoneObj.getString("phone_number"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            getTypeOfNumber(phoneObj
                .getString("phone_type")))
        .build());
}

// Email
final JSONArray emailsArray = obj
.getJSONArray("emails");
for (int j = 0; j < emailsArray.length(); j++) {

    final JSONObject mailObj = emailsArray
    .getJSONObject(j);

    restoredContactList
    .add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            0)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
            mailObj.getString("email_address"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE,
            getTypeOfEmail(mailObj
                .getString("email_type")))
        .build());
}

// Address
final JSONArray addressesArray = obj
.getJSONArray("address");
for (int j = 0; j < addressesArray.length(); j++) {
    final JSONObject addressObj = addressesArray
    .getJSONObject(j);

    restoredContactList
    .add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(
            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            0)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
            addressObj
            .getString("street"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
            addressObj
            .getString("city"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION,
            addressObj
            .getString("state"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
            addressObj
            .getString("zipcode"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY,
            addressObj
            .getString("country"))
        .withValue(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
            getTypeOfAddress(addressObj
                .getString("addressType")))
        .build());
}

// Asking the Contact provider to create a new
// contact
getContentResolver().applyBatch(
    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
    restoredContactList);
```

I am having 128 contacts in my device already.

Basically app is to restore contacts from the server. First time when i restored all contact at that time i deleted all the existing contact from my phone book, it works fine. Now in my phone I am having 128 contacts and I am trying to restore contacts again,but now I got 133 contacts, so 5 of contacts are duplicated in this case. I don't know why is it happening.

I am not getting any error or exception. I think i am making some small mistake,but not able to recognize it. If anyone has any idea,please kindly help me.

Comment: are you sure that those duplicated contacts are alson in phone memory(not stored in sim)

Comment: NO its not sim contact. 1 is stored as google contact and another stored as local (device) contact. But its very strange that every time I insert contact only 4-5 contacts are duplicated and they are fixed that only that 4-5 contacts will be duplicated only. Is it kind of bug in Contacts api or something?